# Invalidate session (logout) in Spring Boot MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, session

I am trying most simple way of logging in and logging out in `Spring MVC`. I am .NET guy and when I remember I implemented session authentication in `ASP.NET` in no time.
Now, I have to use `Spring MVC` and problem I facing is that I get different session object in my `logout` method, so I can't inalidate it.
I am creating session attribute in `login` method and the place where I use my logic is inside my `ProductsController`. Here is code:

**Login method:**

```
 @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping(value = {"login"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity Login(@RequestBody @Valid LoginModel user, HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session){



        List<User> userFromDb=service.findByEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword());
        if(!userFromDb.isEmpty()){
            session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", user );
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```

**Logout method:**

```
 @GetMapping
   @RequestMapping(value = {"logout"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity Logout(HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus 
 status,HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response){

    session.invalidate();
//        request.getSession(true).removeAttribute("loggedInUser");
//
//        request.getSession(true).invalidate();
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies!=null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            cookie.setValue(null);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Products controller:**

```
RequestMapping(value = {"","/"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity Products(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session){

        if(session==null || session.getAttribute("loggedInUser")==null){
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        List<Product> products= service.getAll();
        return new ResponseEntity(products,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I can log in and user is saved in session. However when I logout I can still visit my products page which means that session was not cleared out.

If that is important I am using react app on craeted using `create-react-app` frontend on port `localhost:3000` and my server is on `localhost:8080`.

Comment: The most simple way of doing this is not to write any of that code and to use Spring Security, which has all of this built in.

Comment: @Chrylis can you give me some good tutorial or blog post. There are lot of diffeerent ways, lots of configuration, lots of class names, concepts like beans. It is not simple definitely considering this is first time I write Spring code

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spring security  constraints and logout config , inside your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` config class (implementation) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    .
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()  
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          ....
          .
          .
          .and()
          .logout()
          .invalidateHttpSession(true)
          .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

    }
    ...
    ...
    ...    
}
```

Comment: What this code means, where do I save user to session? Where to put it? Yes I saw this code before. I know use copy/paste but I am not into Spring long enough to have enough knowlegde

Comment: search your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implmentation in the project ? otherwise you donot use spring security ? 
also @VladoPandžić which version of spring you're using ?

Comment: I will see my version when on PC, I created project few days ago so newest probably. This is configuration class which says about routes but how do I autheticate user in login method. Something like SpringSecurity.autheticateUserUsingSession(user)

Comment: May be you use manuel version , not config version ? also is it in xml or annotation

Comment: Spring Boot anotattion version